# Speed up double loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, optimization, numpy, micro-optimization

Is there a way to speed up a double loop that updates its values from the previous iteration?

In code:

```
def calc(N, m):
    x = 1.0
    y = 2.0
    container = np.zeros((N, 2))
    for i in range(N):
      for j in range(m):
        x=np.random.gamma(3,1.0/(y*y+4))
        y=np.random.normal(1.0/(x+1),1.0/sqrt(x+1))
      container[i, 0] = x
      container[i, 1] = y
    return container

calc(10, 5)
```

As you can see, the inner loop is updating variables x and y while the outer loop starts with a different value of x each time. I don't think this is vectorizable but maybe there are other possible improvements.

Thanks!

Comment: "the second loop is updating variables x and y while the first loop starts with a different value of x each time" - I'm not sure what you mean by that. In particular, I don't know what you mean by "starts with a different value of x each time", and "first" or "second" loop is rather unclear compared to "inner" or "outer". I'm not fully sure which is which.

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of much more than replacing `range` with `xrange`. Perhaps you should put a bounty on the question to attract a `numpy` expert

Comment: Sorry. You're right. I will change the first or second loop thing. By _starts with a different value of x each time_, I mean that the first iteration of the outer loop starts with x = 1.0. However, x is modified in the inner loop. Therefore, in the second iteration of the outer loop, x is another value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's going to add up to any important speed up, but you can save some function calls if you generate all your gamma and normally distributed random values at once.

Gamma functions have a [scaling property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Scaling), so that if you draw a value `x` from a gamma(k, 1) distribution, then `c*x` will be a value drawn from a gamma(k, c) distribution. Similarly, with the normal distribution, you can take a `y` value drawn from a normal(0, 1) distribution and convert it into a value drawn from a normal(m, s) distribution doing `x*s + m`. So you can rewrite your function as follows:

```
def calc(N, m):
    x = 1.0
    y = 2.0
    container = np.zeros((N, 2))
    nm = N*m
    gamma_vals = np.random.gamma(3, 1, size=(nm,))
    norm_vals = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(nm,))
    for i in xrange(N):
        for j in xrange(m):
            ij = i*j
            x = gamma_vals[ij] / (y*y+4)
            y = norm_vals[ij]/np.sqrt(x+1) + 1/(x+1)
        container[i, 0] = x
        container[i, 1] = y
    return container
```

If the actual parameters of your distributions had a simpler expression, you may actually be able to use some elaborate form of `np.cumprod` or the like, and spare yourself the loops. I am not able to figure out a way of doing so...

Comment: Unfortunately, this is 2x slower than the approach using np.random.gamma and np.random.normal in the inner loop. Maybe there is a mistake because it doesn't give the same result.

Comment: You are drawing random numbers, so it is no big surprise that results are different. Even if you seeded the random number generator, you are using them in a different order, so again, very normal. As for the performance, this would be a neat trick to use if it allowed removing the loops, which doesn't seem possible with your problem.

Comment: 1+. You're right. Thanks. Do you think there is no way to optimize this further?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
for i in xrange(N): 
   # xrange is an iterator, range makes a new list.
   # You save linear space and `malloc`ing time by doing this

    x += m*y # a simple algebra hack. Compute this line of the loop just once instead of `m` times
    y -= m*x
    y *= -1 # another simple algebra hack. Compute this line of the loop just once instead of `m` times
    container[i,0] = x
    container[i,1] = y
return container
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. xrange is a nice idea. However, the algebra part doesn't apply to the real loop I'm trying to optimize (it involves gamma functions)

Comment: @RobertSmith: sorry, I can't think of very much else right now